# React shows two different value for same prop in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component that receives elementIndex prop as follows:

```
import React from "react";

// Polaris
import { Checkbox, Stack, TextField } from "@shopify/polaris";

// Redux
import { useReduxDispatch, useReduxSelector } from "@app/hook";
import { setNewMenuConfigElement, selectNewMenuConfigElement } from "@slices/menuConfigSlice";

// Components
import { CollapsibleSettingsCard } from "@components/CollapsibleSettingsCard";
import { IconSelector } from "@components/IconSelector";

// Props
type MenuElementSettingsProps = {
  elementIndex: number;
};

export const MenuElementSettings: React.FC<MenuElementSettingsProps> = ({ elementIndex }) => {
  const dispatch = useReduxDispatch();
  const newMenuConfigElement = useReduxSelector(selectNewMenuConfigElement(elementIndex));

  const handleTextChange = (value: string, id: string) => {
    console.log("handleTextChange: ", elementIndex);
    dispatch(
      setNewMenuConfigElement({
        index: elementIndex,
        element: {
          ...newMenuConfigElement,
          [id]: value,
        },
      })
    );
  };

  const handleCheckboxChange = (checked: boolean, id: string) => {
    console.log("handleCheckboxChange: ", elementIndex);
  };

  return (
    <CollapsibleSettingsCard
      id={`menu-element-${elementIndex}-settings`}
      title={`Element ${elementIndex + 1} Settings`}
    >
      <Stack vertical>
        <Stack vertical>
          <Stack.Item>
            <IconSelector elementIndex={elementIndex} />
          </Stack.Item>
          <Stack.Item>
            <TextField
              autoComplete="off"
              id="name"
              label="Name"
              value={newMenuConfigElement.name}
              onChange={handleTextChange}
            />
          </Stack.Item>
          <Stack.Item>
            <TextField
              autoComplete="off"
              id="link"
              label="Link"
              value={newMenuConfigElement.link}
              onChange={handleTextChange}
            />
          </Stack.Item>
          <Stack.Item>
            <Checkbox
              label="Open link in new tab"
              id="openInNewTab"
              checked={newMenuConfigElement.openInNewTab}
              onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
            />
          </Stack.Item>
        </Stack>
      </Stack>
    </CollapsibleSettingsCard>
  );
};
```

Parent of this component is:

```
<Stack.Item>
  <MenuElementSettings elementIndex={0} />
</Stack.Item>
<Stack.Item>
  <MenuElementSettings elementIndex={1} />
</Stack.Item>
<Stack.Item>
  <MenuElementSettings elementIndex={2} />
</Stack.Item>
<Stack.Item>
  <MenuElementSettings elementIndex={3} />
</Stack.Item>
```

When I invoke the handleTextChange function elementIndex prop is received correctly and it updates the correct element in the store.
But when I invoke the handleCheckboxChange function elementIndex prop is always 0.
They are two different functions on same component but one of them is receiving the prop wrong. I have never seen such a thing in my life

and this is the console output when I invoke the functions

```
handleTextChange:  2
handleCheckboxChange:  0
handleTextChange:  1
handleCheckboxChange:  0
```

I would be very happy if someone could help me

Comment: i am not having this issue when reproducing a super minimal example, that just tests the click on the checkbox with props passing. (https://codesandbox.io/s/shopify-polaris-react-playground-forked-j2vdyi?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently it was because of the "id" prop that I was passing to the Checkbox element. The id is hardcoded and same on all components in the dom tree

```
<Checkbox
  label="Open link in new tab"
  id="openInNewTab"
  checked={newMenuConfigElement.openInNewTab}
  onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
/>
```

Even though TextField components also has hardcoded id multiple times on dom tree they were not producing such behavior.

```
<TextField
  autoComplete="off"
  id="name"
  label="Name"
  value={newMenuConfigElement.name}
  onChange={handleTextChange}
/>
<TextField
  autoComplete="off"
  id="link"
  label="Link"
  value={newMenuConfigElement.link}
  onChange={handleTextChange}
/>
```

I think it is a bug with Shopify Polaris library that needs to be fixed